# Accessing list data from a different site in Sharepoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, lookup

Does anyone know if it is possible to Lookup list data from a different site when creating a workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2007? The Define Workflow Lookup dialog only allows you to pick from lists in the current Sharepoint site you are creating the workflow in.
Ideally I'd like to be able to pick from a list in the parent site, or a site from a given URL (eg. http://myserver/mysite)

Comment: I've since realised that I'll need to create a workflow in Visual Studio, since SP Designer workflows hardcode List GUIDs which makes them difficult to deploy to other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with OOTB activities. However you can build a [custom SharePoint designer activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922.aspx) to do the task you need. We usually create just a call web service activity and then we call a SharePoint we service we need.

Take a look at this [CodePlex project](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDActivities) for some custom SharePoint Designer activities.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it looks like the first link is to the wrong location?

Comment: Nice link. There are some useful additions in that Sharepoint Designer Activity project - particularly the Copy List Item Extended which almost got me there.

Answer (score 0):

SPDActivities on CodePlex are very useful. However, if your exact requirements are not covered by any of those activies then you may want to consider embedding c# or vb.net code directly into the SharePoint Designer Workflow (Without resorting to Visual Studio).

I wrote a blog article about how to do it exactly at the following location:

http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/embed-c-or-vb-code-directly-in.html